# Instrument native method in java 13+

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I want to instrument native method in java 13+ (preferably using javassist). Say I want to add logging for particular method and then call real native method. It was possible before via native method prefix (issue https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6263317 and my answer with possible solution with javassist [Editing a native method class with javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663905/editing-a-native-method-class-with-javassist/64973854#64973854)) but since J13 it's not possible to add new method without explicit option (issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221528) which is deprecated from start and can be removed at any time.

There are a lot of questions for this topic like:

- [Retransform native methods in Java Instrumentation Agent library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954192/retransform-native-methods-in-java-instrumentation-agent-library)
- [Editing a native method class with javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663905/editing-a-native-method-class-with-javassist/64973854)
- [native java bytecode instrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960734/native-java-bytecode-instrumentation)
- [Java agent cannot transform all the classes in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790578/java-agent-cannot-transform-all-the-classes-in-my-project)

But none of them covers topic how to wrap native method without `-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods` option in J13+ using javassist. I can replace method body but cannot see next good move. It's quite hard or impossible to implement every interesting native method in pure java and does not scale well so I cannot just replace method. May be I did something wrong in my previous attempt with javassist. Or may be my only option is to use JNA somehow to invoke arbitrary function from jdk libs.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the full answer but maybe will help someone. I suppose there is no generic solution for this in pure-java because name of function does not always follow JNI naming convention and can be registered manually via `RegisterNatives`. So You cannot just create interface for JNA in runtime and use it. If you are not afraid of C/++ and most importantly managing library distribution, specific platform compilation and loading, you can try to lookup pointer to native function from Method(not java Method, see `RegisterNatives` implementation) object, construct contract from java signature and then call it using JNI/JNA. All that being said, I did not find pure-java solution. Still, if you know corresponding native method, you can try several things.

For example, lets look at `Thread.sleep` method (I wanted to instrument it initially).

### First solution

Wait several years. Now it is not native anymore and you can instrument it! Problem is solved!

### Second solution

Replace method with pure-java. You can search for similar method like `parkNanos` and build solution around it (handling "no reason" part too) or block current thread using wait and schedule task in utility thread to wake up current thread via notify. Messy. And you can get different exception during interrupt. Of course there is a problem - how to find replacement and what to do if you want to instrument the replacement too.

I used this method and had 2 branches - AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods enabled or not. Now I need to consider first solution and add third branch.

### Third solution

Suppose you found native method name and it is `JVM_Sleep`. Now you can use JNA to call it. Just add dependency and then declare interface like this:

```
public interface ThreadWrapper extends com.sun.jna.Library {
    void JVM_Sleep(JNIEnv env, Class thisObj, long nanos) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

then call it like this:

```
ThreadWrapper lib = com.sun.jna.Native.load("jvm", ThreadWrapper.class, Collections.singletonMap(Library.OPTION_ALLOW_OBJECTS, Boolean.TRUE));
long nanos = MILLISECONDS.toNanos(millis);
lib.JVM_Sleep(JNIEnv.CURRENT, Thread.class, nanos);
```

Simple solution but requires knowledge about method name, new quite heavy dependency and introduces additional ovehead on JNA.
**Oh, one more thing - `JVM_Sleep` changed contract between versions so it receives millis in older versions and nanos it newer. Of course you should be aware of it and have `if` for that.**

### Forth solution

Java now has foreign functions API and we can use it to call JNI methods.
Main advantage - new API does not need any dependencies.
Main disadvantage - new API does not really have nice and clean bridge to old JNI functions.
Still you can do it like that (error handling are out of scope of example):

```
public void invokeJvmSleepFull(long millis) {
    System.out.println("Start " + new Date());
    try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
        Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
        SymbolLookup jvmLib = SymbolLookup.libraryLookup("jvm", arena);

        // use JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs to get address of running VM
        MemorySegment jniGetCreatedVmsAddr = jvmLib.find("JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs").get();
        FunctionDescriptor jniGetCreatedVmsSig =
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS
                );
        MethodHandle jniGetCreatedVms = linker.downcallHandle(jniGetCreatedVmsAddr, jniGetCreatedVmsSig);
        MemorySegment writtenVmsCount = arena.allocate(ValueLayout.OfInt.JAVA_INT, 0);
        MemorySegment writtenVms = arena.allocateArray(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, 2);
        int code = (int) jniGetCreatedVms.invokeExact(writtenVms, 2, writtenVmsCount);
        if (code != JNI_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected code " + code);
        }
        MemorySegment jvmAddress = writtenVms.get(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, 0);

        // navigate through JavaVM_ -> functions (aka JNIInvokeInterface_) -> GetEnv to get Env address
        StructLayout JavaVM_Layout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
                POINTER.withName("functions")
        ).withName("JavaVM_");
        long functionsOffset = JavaVM_Layout.byteOffset(MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("functions"));
        MemorySegment functionsAddr = jvmAddress.reinterpret(JavaVM_Layout.byteSize()).get(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, functionsOffset);

        StructLayout JNIInvokeInterface_Layout = MemoryLayout.structLayout(
                POINTER.withName("reserved0"),
                POINTER.withName("reserved1"),
                POINTER.withName("reserved2"),
                POINTER.withName("DestroyJavaVM"),
                POINTER.withName("AttachCurrentThread"),
                POINTER.withName("DetachCurrentThread"),
                POINTER.withName("GetEnv"),
                POINTER.withName("AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon")
        ).withName("JNIInvokeInterface_");
        long getEnvOffset = JNIInvokeInterface_Layout.byteOffset(MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("GetEnv"));
        MemorySegment jniGetEnvAddr = functionsAddr.reinterpret(JNIInvokeInterface_Layout.byteSize()).get(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, getEnvOffset);

        FunctionDescriptor jniGetEnvSig =
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT
                );
        MethodHandle jniGetEnv = linker.downcallHandle(jniGetEnvAddr, jniGetEnvSig);
        MemorySegment envAddress = arena.allocate(ValueLayout.ADDRESS);
        code = (int) jniGetEnv.invokeExact(jvmAddress, envAddress, JNI_VERSION_21);
        if (code != JNI_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected code " + code);
        }
        envAddress = envAddress.get(ADDRESS, 0);

        // use env to call JVM_Sleep. It does not use class so just pass null instead.
        MemorySegment jvmSleepAddr = jvmLib.find("JVM_Sleep").get();
        FunctionDescriptor jvmSleepSig =
                FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                        ValueLayout.ADDRESS,
                        ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG);
        MethodHandle threadSleep = linker.downcallHandle(jvmSleepAddr, jvmSleepSig);
        threadSleep.invokeExact(envAddress, MemorySegment.NULL, MILLISECONDS.toNanos(millis));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("End " + new Date());
}
```

This solution has problems of JNA solution except new dependency. And it introduces new problems - it is preview feature, it requires knowledge about structure of `JavaVM_` and `JNIInvokeInterface_` and I am not sure if it is possible to lookup `jclass` through FFI without going native.